# Angular change html tag programmatically when inheriting template

Tags: html, angular, templates, inheritance, tags

I have a Component, DataGrid, which represents a table with expandable rows. Each row, when expanded, shows a child DataGrid table, which is very similar to the parent DataGrid component.
Therefore I defined a base class DataGridComponent, from which the child inherits the both the component and the template. however, I need to change one of the tags in the child's template. Do I have to rewrite the entire template, or could I just point the templateUrl to the parent's template and programmatically change the one html tag that I need to change?

Minimal Example:

**base.component.ts**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'datagrid',
 templateUrl: 'datagrid.component.html'
})
export class DataGridComponent {
    childEnabled:boolean = true;
 // stuff
}
```

**datagrid.component.html**

```
<div>...</div>
<div *ngIf="childEnabled">
    <childgrid
     [options]="childOptions"
     >
    </childgrid>
</div>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'childgrid',
 templateUrl: 'datagrid.component.html' // <-- POINT TO BASECLASS TEMPLATE
})
export class ChildGridComponent extends DataGridComponent{
}
```

**childgrid.component.html** // <-- HOW THE (REAL) TEMPLATE SHOULD BE

```
<div>...</div>
<div *ngIf="childEnabled">
    <grandchildgrid
     [options]="childOptions"
     >
    </grandchildgrid>
</div>
```

**grandchild.component.ts**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'grandchildgrid',
 templateUrl: 'datagrid.component.html' // <-- POINT TO BASECLASS TEMPLATE
})
export class GrandChildGridComponent extends DataGridComponent{
 constructor() {
  super();
  childEnable=false;
 }
}
```

**grandchildgrid.component.html** // <-- HOW THE (REAL) TEMPLATE SHOULD BE

```
<div>...</div>
<div *ngIf="childEnabled">
    <grandchildgrid
     [options]="childOptions"
     >
    </grandchildgrid>
</div>
```

and so on until `childEnabled` is set to `false`. Is there any chance to do something like this and is it something that would make sense from an angularly point of view? Would `ng-content` be of any help in this case?

Comment: I think that you can pass as `@Input` to your DataGridComponent and a `*ngIf` can make the trick. Another option is, in constructor, use some like `constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() private parent:DataGridComponent)` and check if parent is null -see skipSelf in the docs:https://angular.io/api/core/SkipSelf-. NOTE: By the way, in Angular are allowed recursive components, perhaps this is what are you looking for

Comment: thank you, I will take a look at the SkipSelf. My component is not exactly recursive, because each child is derived from a base component, so each nested component is a little bit different from its parent

Answer (score 0):

- The content of DataGrid can go into a separate component and that can be used as a template in both parent and child DataGrid.
- Alternative option is to have the same tags and control behavior using different class and id for parent and child